# Web server cache files

Tags: caching

I have a problem with one of my websites. http://www.weddingguest-book.com

I only found this out because of google webmaster tools but basically I was getting over 100 duplicate meta description errors in my account. However, these were fixed and updated a few months ago. But, whenever I view the page source of one of the pages that is reporting the error in google analytics it is an out of date page. I have uploaded all pages at least 10 times now but the server is still serving the older content. When I view a page (file) via FTP I can see the correct content but when I view in any browser (refreshed a number of times) I still see the old meta description in the source. I could understand it if this was something that happened yesterday but most of these pages are months old now.

So, I have opened a ticket with my hosting provider who will probably take an age to come back to me and tell me to refresh my browser cache. In the meantime I was hoping someone would clarify where hostings servers do indeed using cache files and if so what is the 'norm' when it comes to refreshing these? As advised, many of my pages seem to be serving meta data that is months out of date. I wouldn't think it could be my ISP cache because as advised, these errors are being seen in google webmaster tools.

Thanks in advance for any advise.

Arnie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several places where the caching could be taking place. The mostly like places are the web server of the host or the browser you are using. The easiest way of you checking 100% if it is a caching issue is request a page from a previously unused URL.

For example, www.domain.com/somepage.html can be called via www.domain.com/somepage.html?somequerystring

If a ctrl+f5 refresh gives you a cached page but the technique above gives you a new page then it's a hosting cache issue that only they can resolve. If the technique above still gives you the cached page, then there is something wrong with the configuration of your hosting account.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have tried all methods from my end and have even deleted some pages off the server but they still keep coming up. I will have to wait and see what the hosting company comes back with. I thought most hosting companies refreshed every 24 to 28 hours but this can't be the case because some of the old pages that are being served were updated months ago.

Comment: No problem. I would appreciate you marking the question as answered if you could. Sorry I couldn't help any more.

Comment: Next to my answer (on the left) is a number with some up and down arrows. Below that is a tick. Click the tick. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work